# How combine make diagonal column heads in table with multicolumn headers

Tags: tables

1. I want to fit this table on a portrait format page
2. and make the columns that show numbers to be of equal width

   however, type 3 has a longer name than the others, hence
3. setting the column heads diagonally might help me fit the longer name in
   so that condition 1. can be fulfilled

this example **does not work** 
and I seem to need some advice on how to combine `\rotatebox` with `\multicolumn`

or maybe you have a different idea altogether how I can solve this with conditions 1. and 2.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} \usepackage{babel} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{dcolumn} \usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{table}  
\centering  
\caption{Caption text}  
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} | p{0.45cm} |}  
\hline  
 & \multicolumn{2}{*}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{*}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{*}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 3 longer text}} & \multicolumn{2}{*}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 4}} & \multicolumn{2}{*}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 5}} & \multicolumn{2}{*}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 6}}\\\hline  
\multicolumn{13}{|l|}{\textsc{\textbf{row title bold}}} \\ \hline  
Criterium 1 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 \\ \hline  
Criterium 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 \\ \hline  
\multicolumn{13}{|l|}{\textsc{\textbf{row title bold}}} \\ \hline  
Criterium 3 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline  
Criterium 4 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline  
\textbf{\textsc {Sum}} &  & \textbf{84} & & \textbf{56} & & \textbf{50}& &  \textbf{53}& & \textbf{51}& & \textbf{51} \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}  
\label{tab:Label text}  
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: You wrongly use `\multicolumn`. You can use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\rotatebox{60}{Type 1}}`, but never use `*`.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, you can place the heading elements in a `\makebox[<len>][<align>]{<stuff>}` that will typeset `<stuff>` in a box of width `<len>`, even if `<stuff>` is wider/thinner than `<len>`. The alignment specification `<align>` is similar to that of the `array` or `tabular` column specification.

The following MWE provides `\rothead[<angle>]{<stuff>}` (as a redefinition from the [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell)) that rotates `<stuff>` by angle `<angle>` (default is `60` degrees with this argument being optional). It also places `<stuff>` in a box of fixed `9mm` width, centered `c`. Additionally you can use `\\` to make a newline within `<stuff>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{makecell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell
\renewcommand{\rothead}[2][60]{\makebox[9mm][c]{\rotatebox{#1}{\makecell[c]{#2}}}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}  
  \centering  
  \caption{Caption text}  
  \begin{tabular}{|l|*{12}{p{0.45cm}|}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rothead{Type 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rothead{Type 2}} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rothead{Type 3 longer text\\than other headings}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rothead{Type 4}}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rothead{Type 5}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rothead{Type 6}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|l|}{\textsc{\textbf{row title bold}}} \\ \hline
    Criterion 1 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 \\ \hline  
    Criterion 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 \\ \hline  
    \multicolumn{13}{|l|}{\textsc{\textbf{row title bold}}} \\ \hline  
    Criterion 3 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline  
    Criterion 4 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline  

    \textbf{\textsc{Sum}} & & \textbf{84} & & \textbf{56} & & \textbf{50} & & \textbf{53} 
      & & \textbf{51} & & \textbf{51} \\ \hline  
  \end{tabular}  
  \label{tab:Label text}  
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

If you're interested in seeing the size of the boxes that the rotated headings are contained, use the following redefinition of `\rothead` instead:

```
\renewcommand{\rothead}[2][60]{\framebox[9mm][c]{\rotatebox{#1}{\makecell[c]{#2}}}}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just use `tabularx`. I didn't change much of the contents of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{2}{X|}{#1}}
\centering
\caption{Caption text}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{12}{R|}}
\hline
 & \MC{Type~1} & \MC{Type~2} & \MC{Type~3 longer text}
 & \MC{Type~4} & \MC{Type~5} & \MC{Type~6}\\\hline
\multicolumn{13}{|l|}{\textsc{\textbf{row title bold}}} \\ \hline
Criterium 1 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 5 & 10 \\ \hline
Criterium 2 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 8 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{13}{|l|}{\textsc{\textbf{row title bold}}} \\ \hline
Criterium 3 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \hline
Criterium 4 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\textbf{\textsc{Sum}}
 && \textbf{84} && \textbf{56} && \textbf{50}
 && \textbf{53} && \textbf{51} && \textbf{51} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:Label text}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]