# Can't get correct ps output using tikzmark

Tags: dvi, ps, tikzmark

I was using [tables-in-latex-with-diagonal-first-row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78938/tables-in-latex-with-diagonal-first-row) as a guideline and everything was working fine as long as I kept using pdflatex in texmaker to get the pdf file.

However, for submission I need a ps file and this is not generated, so I tried using Latex and dvips, but the table just didn't look right anymore.
Next, I tried using pdflatex with dvi output followed by dvips, still the same problem.

Any idea how to solve this? I add an example table code,  correct output and messed up output below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate (#1);}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{T}[2]{@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}C{#2}@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\tikzmark{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[inner xsep=-\pgflinewidth,inner ysep=-\pgflinewidth] at (0,0) (mytable){%
\begin{tabular}{|T{a}{0.13\columnwidth}|T{b}{0.08\columnwidth}|T{c}{0.08\columnwidth}|T{d}{0.08\columnwidth}|T{e}{0.08\columnwidth}|T{f}{0.08\columnwidth}|c|}
\hline 
t1                  & + &    & +   & ++ &    \\
t2                  &   &    & +   &    &    \\
t3  &   &    & +   &    &    \\
t4                  & + &    & +   &    &    \\
t5                  &   &    &     &    & ++ \\
t6      &   & ++ &     & +  &    \\
t7                  &   & ++ &     & +  &    \\
t8                  &   & +  &     & ++ &    \\
t9                  &   & +  &     & ++ &    \\
t10                 &   &    & +++ &    &    \\

\hline
\end{tabular}

};
\draw (mytable.north east) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north-|a) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north-|b) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north-|c) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north-|d) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north-|e) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north-|f) --++ (30:1.475cm);
\draw (mytable.north east) ++ (30:1.475cm) --([shift={(30:1.4cm)}]mytable.north-|a);
%
\node[rotate=30,anchor=west] at ($(mytable.north-|b)!0.5!(mytable.north-|a)$) {f1};
\node[rotate=30,anchor=west] at ($(mytable.north-|c)!0.5!(mytable.north-|b)$) {f2};
\node[rotate=30,anchor=west] at ($(mytable.north-|c)!0.5!(mytable.north-|d)$) {f3};
\node[rotate=30,anchor=west] at ($(mytable.north-|d)!0.5!(mytable.north-|e)$) {f4};
\node[rotate=30,anchor=west] at ($(mytable.north-|e)!0.5!(mytable.north-|f)$) {f5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Overview}
\label{tab:overview}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

This is what it should look like
[image: Good example]

This is the output when using the route TEX->DVI->PS
[image]

Comment: If every thing fails, you can use some other tool like `pdftops` or `ghostscript` to convert pdf to ps. With `pdftops` it is `pdftops -eps file.pdf file.ps`

Comment: Thanks, I did end up using pdftops back then if I remember correctly.
At the moment I used the 'save as' of adobe acrobat pro, after realizing we it at work.